# Sulu CMF - Reuse content of different webspace

Tags: php, symfony, sulu

I have Sulu CMF in place with two webspaces, one for US and one for EU. Some pages of the two webspaces are identical, so instead of creating the pages individually for each webspace, I used the page type "Internal Link" in the US webspace, and pointed to the page in the EU webspace.

Unfortunately, if I open the respective url on the US site, the browser gets redirected (301) to the page on the EU site, instead of just loading the page contents on the US site.

Is there any way how I can accomplish this without a redirect?
Or is there another way, to share pages among different webspaces?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds for me like you did miss the `sulu_content_path` twig extension to give the target webspace to it, something like `sulu_content_path(item.url, item.webspaceKey)` should generate absolute url with the target webspace.

https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.5/reference/twig-extensions/functions/sulu_content_path.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. In fact the target webspace is passed to `sulu_content_path` and the resulting URL is also the correct one. But the url is then redirected with a `301` response code to the webspace url where the page originates.